# Filtering ItemSource collection for many ComboBoxes separately

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `UserControl` with `ItemsControl`. `ItemsControl` contains an empty list of `ComboBox`es and two buttons Add and Remove. So I can have several `ComboBox`es on the panel.
`ComboBox`es have the same `ItemsSource`es.
How can I filter the Source collection for each  `ComboBox` to show only unused (not selected in other comboboxes) items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose you have your ComboBox ItemSource property attached to a list of string like this:

```
public List<string> OriginalList = new List<string>
{
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
 };
```

You can have a list of selected values, something like:

```
List<string> SelectedValues = new List<string>();
```

After this you can attach a method to the SelectionChanged property of the ComboBox to get the selected value and add it to the SelectedValues list:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
 <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Name="comboBox"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;
   SelectedValues.Add(text);
}
```

After this you only have to check what items are not in your ItemSouce list with Except:

```
List<string> unusedItems = OriginalList.Except(SelectedValues).ToList();
```